# The pointer turns to hand even when there is no hyperlink

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, hyperlinks

In the reputation tab, while hovering over various activities, the mouse turns to hand when there is a hyperlink like the link to post in case of upvotes and downvotes and the learn more page when there is a change of rep due to user removal.

But when there is a loss in reputation due to user removal **in some cases**, the pointer turns to hand even over the areas where there is no hyperlink like the last one in the below GIF.

[image]

It works fine only for certain cases, like the one below. Here there is no change in pointer to hand over areas with no hyperlinks (when there is loss of rep due to user removal)

[image]

---

The following one shows the cases a bit more clearly.

[image]

Can this be made consistent everywhere?

Answer (score 9):

I managed to repro with vote reversals as well. As per my observation, this is unrelated to hyperlinks. Hovering anywhere over the row will show a hand cursor. This normally (and correctly) happens with rows that can be expanded to show a child table.

It looks like certain "user removed"/"voting corrected" row elements (incorrectly?) have a `expandable-row` class:

[image]

Once that class is removed, the default cursor is shown:

[image]

My guess is that in those cases, the vote correction includes *multiple events* but they're hidden from the user and the code checks the actual count rather than the count of events shown to the user.

Comment: Thanks! Just now observed that in case of multiple events with user removal, hand shows up but the expandable rows are hidden.

Comment: So is that a [``status-bydesign``](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) ?

Comment: @Ak. It depends on whether or not the developers consider it a bug (I'm not an SE employee) and whether it's worth the time to implement a fix. Let's wait for a staff member to step in.